# Rails: Pushing Data to Client with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an app that allows users to post much like facebook. I have developed the app in its entirety except for pushing notifications of new posts to the user.

I plan on deploying to Heroku, which posses a problem. Heroku does not currently support websockets. In other words, if I want to implement websockets, I am going to have to run those processes on a different server, use a gem, or the like.

My question is, what is the most efficient & simple way to push notifications to users using Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins available on heroku for push support:

- [Pubnub](https://addons.heroku.com/pubnub)
- [Pusher](https://addons.heroku.com/pusher)